# Exibir informações do User Profile do Wordpress na página, apenas quando o respectivo campo está preenchido

Tags: php, wordpress

Criei campos para as mídias sociais no editor de perfil para um template. Testei em links estáticos e estão funcionando corretamente:

```php
 function author_social_media ($profile_fields){

    $profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';

    return $profile_fields;

    $facebookHandle = the_author_meta('facebook');

}
```

O que estou tentando fazer é mostra-los apenas quando estão preenchidos, mas não estou tendo sucesso. O preenchimento não é obrigatório. Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```html
<section>    
<?php if(isset($profile_fields['facebook']){
        echo "<a href="<?php the_author_meta('facebook'); ?>">Facebook</a>";
        } else{
        echo '';
        }
?>
</section>
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica se o seu teste não está vindo como uma `string` vazia, pois o comando `isset` só verifica se é nulo, segundo esse link:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php

Então faça o teste assim:

```
if($profile_fields['facebook'] != "")
```

Outra coisa, reparei que no código que você postou, no `IF` mesmo, falta fecha um parenteses ")". Dá uma olhada nisso também.

Comment: Sugiro o [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, funcionou.